# How to chunk an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one dimensional array it's like this

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

I need to put each 3 element in two dimensional array 
to be after that like

```
$newarr = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]);
```

Is there any keyword in PHP can do this?

Comment: the problem is to define thee element in each one of them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk)**

```
print_r(array_chunk($arr,3));
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/374052)**

Comment: but how can i put it in array ? 
i idid some thing like this but it's not working
$a[]=array_chunk($download,3);

Comment: Simple. `$new_array=array_chunk($arr,3);`

Comment: i'm sorry i did it like what you said but the problem was i put [] thanks for your help

Comment: That syntax is not wrong but it is used when you have to add an element to an existing array. And since in this case we are creating a new array we don't need `[]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_chunk`

```
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
$newarr=array_chunk($arr,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_chunk`

```
<?php

$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
print_r(array_chunk($arr,3));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_chunk.

```
<?php
$input_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);;
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 3));
?>
```

check this link for further refr.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `array_chunk`

```
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
print_r(array_chunk($arr,3));
```